# Date difference calculation

Tags: cognito-forms

I'm looking to find out what formula to use to calculate the difference between two dates and display it in number of days, months, and years elapsed.  For example:

Today's Date: 6/2/2017
Date of Surgery: 5/3/2014
Time Elapsed: 2years, 11 months, 29days

Doesn't have to be super exact so don't have to take into account leap year and assume 30 days for each month.

I can get number of days by `=(Date of Surgery - Today's Date).days` but how to convert this number to years, months, and days?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a developer with [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

This can be set up, but it will not be exact as we don't take into account leap years and we are setting a month to be 30 days.

You will want to start out with a Calculation field labeled 'Total Days' set to the type of 'Number' with 0 decimal places. The following calculation can then be used.

```
=(TodaysDate - DateOfSurgery).Days
```

You will then need to set up 3 more Calculation fields. One for Years, one for Months, and one for Days. I labeled each of them as such.

For the Years field you will want to use the following calculation to round down, and get the number of years based on the number of days between the two dates. For each of the Calculation fields you will want to set the Type to 'Number' and again set the Decimal Places to 0.

```
=Math.Floor(TotalDays/365)
```

You will then want to do the same for Months and Days. Months would use the following calculation.

```
=Math.Floor((TotalDays - Math.Floor(Years)*365)/30.42)
```

Days would use the following calculation.

```
=TotalDays - Math.Floor(Years)*365 - Math.Floor(Months)*30.42
```

Once this is fully set up you will be able to preview your form and get the following.

[image]

I have also provided the template link to the form we used for testing so that you can make a copy to your own Organization.

https://www.cognitoforms.com/templates/shared/DemoAccountForCognitoForms/DateDifferenceCalculation